# Connect to remote mysql database from within a container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-network

From my local computer, I can easily connect to a remote instance of mysql database using the mysql cli command (assuming environment variables are set):

```
# mysql -u root -p$DB_PASSWORD -h $DB_HOST --port=$DB_PORT

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7365
Server version: 5.7.14-google (Google)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

However, using docker it just hangs:

```
docker run --rm -it --name mysql -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes mysql \
mysql -u root -p$DB_PASSWORD -h $DB_HOST --port=$DB_PORT

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
show databases;
^C
^C
exit
exit
^C
```

and have to `docker container stop mysql` from another terminal window for it to exit the mysql container.

I tried even attaching to the container and run the same command to no avail. Tried connecting to an AWS MySQL instance and Google Cloud SQL instance, also tried to enter variables directly in the command line all with the same result. Why is it hanging and how can I make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Are the values of all of those environment variables set?

Comment: Yes, I even tried to add them directly both on the docker command and when attached to the container.

Comment: Just to take the variables out of it, I would try to connect with those parameters passed as string literals.   It does seem that the docker networking might be wonky.  Try restarting docker and see if it fixes it.  `sudo systemctl restart docker` on a *nix.

Comment: Can you get to any other servers outside the container? Is the DB_HOST value an IP address or a hostname?

Comment: Yes I can ping $DB_HOST with no problem from inside the container.

Comment: I suspect $IP_ADDRESS is a loopback address like 127.0.0.1.  Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Google Cloud SQL and the IP address needed to be whitelisted for it to allow access. So adding that solved the connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try expose the default port for MySQL

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 ...
```

Comment: still hangs! :(

Comment: mmm run the container on the same host network, maybe the mysql cli need another ports too. maybe! 
only for test:

***docker run --net=host ***

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the ways but below step has resolved my issue.
run command inside container

dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

it will ask you to select for Geographical area and Time zone, then you are done.